# Eyebrow mesh, Eyelash mesh move seperatly from rest of head

Tags: modeling, mesh

I went through the suggested posts that came up when I typed this title and they did not solve my issue.

I have a model created with the Make Human program. head, eyebrows, hair, teeth, eyelashes are all separate meshes. When I tilt the head back the eyebrow and eyelashes sink down into the head. All the other meshes move with the head properly. I have tried to join the eyebrow and eyelash meshes to the head, when I did they disappeared.
[image: head normal position]
[image: head tilted back, eyebrow and eyelash mesh move into head]

Comment: It is possibly a weight missmatch. Could you post the file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5137" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5137/)

Comment: Did it upload properly?